# Creating a new font in Java

Tags: java, fonts

I'm trying to create a `font` in `Java`, I have looked in other posts but I'm really new at this and It's kind of difficult.
Here's my code.

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("fuente/TalkingToTheMoon.ttf")));
```

I know I need a `try-catch` for the `exception` but before I do that I get this message in `Netbeans: "package ge doesn't exist"` I don't know exactly what this mean, In the project I have in the Source Package 3 Packages which are `Images`, `Font` and `SieteYMedia`, which is the program itself. 
Sorry for the inconvenience, any help? Thanks.

Comment: Did you use correct imports? I think these should be the ones you neeed:
import java.awt.Font; import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
If imports are correct, please post a little bit more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

The code needs some lines to do the exceptions:

```
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    try {
        ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("fuente/TalkingToTheMoon.ttf")));
    } catch (FontFormatException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(EditTitlesJUnitTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(EditTitlesJUnitTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Also it needs some imports:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
```

Comment: It keeps getting me the same error. I don't know if I had to add something more. I have both imports, font and graphics enviroment.

Comment: @user3332748 please, publish the neighbouring code, too. Also, mark the line where the error happens. Also, publish the error log.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll try to explain better. I have a JFrame with many objects, TextFields, JLabels, Buttons etc.. I want to use a custom font in some labels in my JFrame. I have a lot of code but It's irrelevant to what i'm doing to the font, The only relevant code I have is the one I showed to you guys. I don't know if I have to include it in a method or something

Comment: @Daredawk at least, you could  show the line where the error happens.

Comment: This is the only thing I can show you, I don't know what more to show :( http://i.imgur.com/RoF79zJ.png http://i.imgur.com/3141BEA.png

Comment: @Daredawk Ah! You have the compiler error! You had to mention it! Click on the red little lamp to the left - surely, you lack some imports.

Comment: Ups, I forgot to add the imports later, anyway I keep getting this error. http://i.imgur.com/aee4A7e.png Sorry for not explaining myself good, i'm reaally new at this and sometimes I don't really know what I'm seeing in the error messages.

Comment: @Daredawk you still have some problems with import. On y com these two strings need only import and try/catch for a possible exception. What imports do you have?

Comment: import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment; Those are the only ones.

Comment: @Daredawk ge is interpreted as package - it is because the previous line is not accepted for true. Have you restarted the Netbeans?

Comment: @Daredawk more problem are possible - if you have not some libraries installed or some your libraries are installed as libraries and as jars simultaneously. The last simply makes NetBeans mad. Also mixing jars and java sources in one folder can cause not finding classes.

Comment: Yup, I have restarted Netbeans and I have tested it on another computers and keeps getting the same error. What do you advice me to do then?

Comment: @Daredawk I have just taken my code and put it into a new java project in freshly installed NetBeans. All is OK. So, you have problems with your IDE. I need more info. Please, put here images of the error, that you see when hovering over the line with error and when hovering over that lamp to the left.